# Terraform - AKS Private Cloud | Infinite wait on helm relase

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

- I am trying to create a Private Cloud on AKS with Terraform.
- The public route seemd to work fine and I am putting in security stuff, step by step
- After putting in Networks azurerm_virtual_network, azurerm_subnet it seems to hand my Helm Deployment
- There are no logs, its just an infinite wait.
- `helm_release.ingress: Still creating... [11m0s elapsed]` (this is a simple NGINX Ingress Controller)

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "foo_network" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.foo_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.foo_group.name
  address_space       = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.foo_network.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.foo_group.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.1.0.0/22"]
}
```

**Any points on how should I debug this? Lack of logs is making it difficult to understand.**

---

Complete Script

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "foo" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-k8s-resources"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "foo" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-k8s"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.foo.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.foo.name
  dns_prefix          = "${var.prefix}-k8s"

  default_node_pool {
    name           = "system"
    node_count     = 1
    vm_size        = "Standard_D4s_v3"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  addon_profile {
    aci_connector_linux {
      enabled = false
    }

    azure_policy {
      enabled = false
    }

    http_application_routing {
      enabled = false
    }

    kube_dashboard {
      enabled = true
    }

    oms_agent {
      enabled = false
    }
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  version = "~> 1.11.3"

    load_config_file       = false
    host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.foo.kube_config.0.host
    username               = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.foo.kube_config.0.username
    password               = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.foo.kube_config.0.password
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.foo.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

provider "helm" {
  # Use provider with Helm 3.x support
  version = "~> 1.2.2"
}

resource "null_resource" "configure_kubectl" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az aks get-credentials --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.foo.name} --name ${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.foo.name} --overwrite-existing"

    environment = {
      KUBECONFIG = ""
    }
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.foo]
}

resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
  name       = "ingress-foo"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
  timeout    = 3000
  depends_on = [null_resource.configure_kubectl]
}
```

Comment: where are you running your terraform script from ?

Comment: coud you share your full stripped down terraform script ? 
It seems that you are cutting your access to the API Server when you setup the networking. hence your Helm provider looses access

Comment: ok I will edit to share the full snippet. I am running from AKS Default Terminal (cloud shell)

Comment: It seems the script I was refereing to was got complete. got a more complete reference.

Comment: @SrinathGanesh why do you use null resources in this context?

Comment: @shan, null resource gives u a dedicated step where u can have `local-exec`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to debug this is to be able to `kubectl` into the AKS cluster. (AKS should have documentation on how to set up `kubectl`.)

Then, play around with `kubectl get pods -A` and see if anything jumps out as being wrong. Specifically, look for nginx-ingress pods that are not in a `Running` status.

If there are such pods, debug further with `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` or `kubectl logs -f <pod_name>`, depending on whether the issue happens after the container has successfully started up or not.

Comment: It seems the script I was refereing to was got complete. got a more complete reference.